# What is a more modern .NET library to use with Active Directory than System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement?

Tags: active-directory

We are looking to update our .NET C# codebase with a more modern library to use with Active Directory than System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement. Anything newer is preferred, but we are specifically looking for a library that works well with data on our servers and in the cloud (as we migrate there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much more current do you want? https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/ was last updated 6mo ago. It works in .net6 and core, and I'm currently working on a web app that uses it. I would say that at least from Microsoft this is the latest that there is, outside of System.DirectoryServices, which was also updated 6mo ago.